# setting onClickListener on views drawn on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview, onclicklistener

So basically I have some image views drawn over my canvas, but when I try to set up onclick listeners and try to handle events, it doesn't work.

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnClickListener{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    RectF rf = new RectF(30, 30, 80, 80);
    BallView ball = new BallView(getContext());
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ball.setOnClickListener(this);
        ball.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 110, 10, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Mock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

BallView.java

```
public class BallView extends ImageView {
Paint b = new Paint();
public BallView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void onDraw(Canvas c){
    b.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    c.drawCircle(50, 50, 40, b);
}
```

}

Comment: *it doesn't work* - And what exactly happens? What is `BallView`? If it extends View please move the initialization for the *ball* and *bmp* in the constructor of `DrawView`.

Comment: is it clickable? Have You called  setClickable(true) for it?

Comment: @Luksprog Did as you said but didn't work

Comment: @sandrstar tried that too, no change

Comment: @MachMitch have you got any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer is: Your view is not receiving touch events, because it's not in views hierarchy, so click callback is also not called. Actually, view should be in View hierarchy (in other words, added to some upper level view and finally, to the window) in order to participate is user interactions.
So, if You want to implement somthing covering Your view, then it should be ViewGroup or shouldn't be related to view at all and be some abstract container.
E.g. using the way below click works without any issues (but You will need second view or modify BallView to draw bmp):
DrawView:

```
public class DrawView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener {
    BallView ball = new BallView(getContext());

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        addView(ball);
        ball.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Mock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

`BallView` class stays the same.
Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.ruinalst.performance.tests.views.DrawView
            android:id="@+id/oscillator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's true but the main reason i want to work  with canvas rather than layouts is that my game has animations and movements which can be redrawn on canvas easily. Although i m beginner, correct me if i am wrong here. But thank you @sandrstar for your input.

Comment: Then I would suggest to check Pro Android Games book  (try to search 'Pro Android Games pdf' on google) - it contains some basic examples of drawing on canvas. Regarding touch handling, it might be better to check touch coordinates in Your own function and don't relay on ClickListeners (however, I'm not very experienced with games development).